# Block specific browser without using User-Agent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cloudflare

React app. I want to block specific browser (Kiwi Mobile) from my site. But i can't use `User-Agent` header, because people, who using site also using chrome extension, which change `User-Agent` in requests. So, is there any other ways to get browser info?

I tried to detect extension, but it works like a VPN extension: intercepts requests and then send changed data to my servers. I blocked an extension IP in Cloudflare, but it works only for a week, then they start using proxy servers, and detect all proxy servers is nearly impossible.

I need to block using this browser by React app (just not load the page if it is a kiwi browser). Or maybe, block it by cloudflare, if it's possible

Comment: @padeso Because extension uses js fetch library to make api requests, but i need to block Browser, cause this browser can load an extension on android. most of users using android to access site, it's mobile web app. If i block access with this browser, most of users will unable to use extention

Comment: Basically no it's not possible. You need to take a step back here. What attack is occurring exactly? Are they pounding the API? Are they automating something? It would be better to fix what ever is being exploited via limits or auto-banning based on certain behaviours etc in the application later, than to play their game of cat and mouse.

Comment: @adsy They're sends malformed requests to api and change html on front end with their code. For example, i have an images on server and endpoint to get them and make them as viewed. They change images to their, get links to my images, saving and changing on their server, and then load it from their server and show modified images

Comment: Gotcha. The best solution to this would be to implement cookie-based sessions on your back end image endpoint, and require the session to be valid to load the image. This would prevent the attackers back end from being able to load the image endpoint without a session. I.e. the cookie header set. From this point, you can easily identify which sessions are abusing the system. From that point I would probably implement heuristics that detect that automatically in the app code (rate limiting for example), and then autoban those server IP's by integrating with cloudflare api.

Comment: This makes life a lot harder for them as they now need to write code to actually create a session on your real site, and this is also a mechanism for you to identify offenders and ban both or one of their accounts and IPs automatically based on some rules about realistic behaviour.

Comment: @adsy Alright, thank's a lot, i'll try to do that